# Dynamic function call C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to do something like this:

```
class Base{};
class Specialized1 : public Base
{
public:
    int GetCount(){ return 1; }
};
class Specialized2 : public Base
{
public:
    bool IsCorrect() { return true; }
};

class Example
{
public:
    template< class ATTR_CLASS, class RETURNED_PARAMETER_CLASS >
    int GetPerfectAttributeIndex( const RETURNED_PARAMETER_CLASS & perfect_parameter, ***RETURNED_PARAMETER_CLASS (*function_to_call)()*** )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < AttributeCount; ++i )
        {
            if ( perfect_parameter ==
                static_cast< ATTR_CLASS >( MyAttributeTable[ i ] )->function_to_call() )
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    Base** MyAttributeTable;
    int AttributeCount;
};
```

And the call would be:

```
example.GetPerfectAttributeIndex< Specialized1, int >( 1, &Specialized1::GetCount );
```

So I know that this code is not working because of the part between ***
But how can I change it to make it work? Using some C++11 magic?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You might want to read about e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `function_to_call` is not a pointer to member function. You should also downcast from `Base*` more safe with `dynamic_cast` and checking against `nullptr` afterwards.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Specialized1 : public Base
{
public:
    int GetCount() { return 1; }
};

class Specialized2 : public Base
{
public:
    bool IsCorrect() { return true; }
};

class Example
{
public:
    template <class ATTR_CLASS, class RETURNED_PARAMETER_CLASS>
    int GetPerfectAttributeIndex(
        RETURNED_PARAMETER_CLASS const& perfect_parameter,
        RETURNED_PARAMETER_CLASS(ATTR_CLASS::*function_to_call)()) // added ATTR_CLASS::
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < AttributeCount; ++i)
        {
            auto ptr = dynamic_cast<ATTR_CLASS*>(MyAttributeTable[i]);

            if(!ptr)
            {
                // handle the case of an invalid cast
            }

            if(perfect_parameter == (ptr->*function_to_call)()) // extra parentheses added and ->* operator used
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    Base** MyAttributeTable;
    int AttributeCount;
};
```

Comment: Downcasting each `Base*` and calling a member function of, e.g.,  `Specialized1` doesn't sound like the best idea, it's a pathway to UB

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki Indeed it isn't. But I don't have better solution to offer, apart from fixing the compile errors. Do you?

Comment: at least use a `dynamic_cast` and check if the pointer is not nullptr prior to calling the function

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki Had that for a moment, but then I saw yours with `static_cast` few seconds before posting and that baffled me.

Comment: Ok I have a compile error now saying that:
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
(everytime I call the GetPerfectAttributeIndex)
It's like the compiler can not make the binding between the function parameter "function_to_call" and the call to the function inside the function body.
Any idea?

Comment: @Silouane On which line does it happen? Sorry, I posted erroneous code - members were local variables.

Comment: When I call:
example.GetPerfectAttributeIndex< Specialized1, int >( 1, &Specialized1::GetCount );

Comment: Yes, I've seen your change, but that was not the error.
The error happens when I call the function from example.

Comment: @Silouane What compiler are you using? This works for me in VS 2013 and on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0afeb90df031b6d0) as well.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much. My problem was that I didn't see correctly where you put your extra parenthesis. But now it's perfect.

Comment: @Silouane Glad I could help.